# Can I preserve the shelf-life of a cannoli?

Tags: storage-method, cream

I plan on purchasing some cannolis from a local bakery and will bring on a trip with me to some friends. Since my trip will span a few days, I want to try to preserve the cannolis until I can deliver them to my friends.

The one time I have tried this before (a half day's worth of driving), I placed the cannolis in an icebox to prevent the cream from spoiling but results in a slightly soggy and moist shell.

Is there a way to prevent the cream from spoiling but also keeping the shell hard and crunchy? The bakery I am getting the cannolis from makes them in-house daily (since it's a very popular local spot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've proved already there's only one way to do this - buy the shells "unloaded" and fill them when you get there.

Assuming the bakery people are nice, ask them to put the filling in an icing bag and refrigerate that until you arrive. Put the shells separately in a cake tin, load the shells when you get to your destination.

I'm sure that everyone concerned will understand why you want to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered one way to keep them crisp in the fridge for at least a day and a half to two days...I wrap each cannoli separately by rolling them in wax paper, then fold over each end and tape it (try to tape it so that air will not get to it). Then take each and roll them up in aluminum foil. I then put it in a ziplock bag, don't know if this is necessary, but I do it anyway. It doesn't keep them for a week, but better than having them soggy after four hours. :-)